# Windows 8 doesn't want to print via IPP although it detects the printer

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, printing, printer

I have:

- Router **Comtrend AR-5387un** in `192.168.0.1`, with USB and integrated IPP printing server.
- Printer **Samsung ML-1710**, connected using USB to the router.
- **Windows 8.1 Update 1 Professional x64**, up to date and connected to the router.

  - IPP feature installed correctly (and reinstalled several times because of this)

When I add the printer in the Control Panel, **it's detected succesfully** and it asks for the drivers, which it installs promptly. The URL that I input is `http://192.168.0.1:631/printers/samsung`. Meanwhile, if I capture traffic with Wireshark, **I can even some IPP requests back an forth**. *Yay!*

But when I try to print something, be it the test page or some text with Notepad, I get this ***printer in an error state*** error:

[image: Printer in an error state]

I can see with Wireshark that when trying to print, **not a single request is sent to the network, the error message is shown immediately**, and then the job stays in the queue indefinitely until deleted.

Also, the printer was working perfectly in Windows XP in this same computer a few days ago,  with the same exact URL, and it's working right now in another computer with Windows XP in the same network.

Searching some info I found **[KB2850453](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2850453)**, but since I don't see any traffic in the network it doesn't seem to be the cause.

**These suggestions can't be done right now:**

- Sharing the printer in other computer where the printer is working
- Buying a new printer or print server
- Connect the printer to the computer directly (not physically possible)
- *"The address in that image is wrong!"* Nope, that's how Windows seems to understand IPP. The computer with Windows XP where the printer is working shows the address formatted that way too.
- Restart computer/router/printer/printing service/whatever. Everything has been restarted a million times already! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm baffled. I renamed the printer in the router configuration (from "samsung" to "ml1710") and **everything started working again**. I... just don't have any explanation, but now it's working in Windows 8 and Windows XP (after reconfiguring with the new name) without any problems. I guess the router just went crazy for a moment, but I still can't explain the lack of outgoing packets from the computer.

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung ML-1710 is a GDI printer. GDI printers are designed to be low cost, and part of the cost-cutting is the omission of a "Page Definition Language" like PCL or PostScript. Not having a PDL, the printer relies on the Windows graphics engine to convert the page into dots on the paper.

GDI printers are notoriously difficult to network. There are 2 good ways to do it:

1. Plug the printer into a PC and share it from there.
2. Connect the printer via USB to a **compatible** printserver. Most printserver manufacturers provide a list of printers compatible with their device. I had a look on the Comtrend website, but I could not find your router, nor could I find a compatibility list for their other routers.

While it is odd that the same setup works with XP, I can only put that down to the idiosyncrasies of GDI.

As you cannot connect the printer to a PC, there seem to be only 2 options open:

1. Buy a printer that supports PCL, e.g. [Samsung SL-M2835DW](http://www.samsung.com/au/consumer/print-solutions/print-multifunctions-copiers/mono-laser-printer/SL-M2835DW/XSA-spec)
2. Buy a printserver that supports your printer, e.g. [Netgear PS121](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1093/~/netgear-print-server-compatibility-list-%28-2005-%29)

Comment: I'm very thankful for your complete answer but the problem just seemed to solve itself... I renamed the printer in the router and everything started working again. Check my answer. Thank you again!